# Having different ORDER BY for each column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

Hello  all :) I'd like to select some values in one column according to a specific order of other columns, and use a different order for the next column.

I'm using this at the moment, but it won't fulfill what I intend to do:

```
SELECT
  LAST_VALUE(FIELD_INFO_1) OVER (ORDER BY FIELD_A),
  LAST_VALUE(FIELD_INFO_2) OVER (ORDER BY FIELD_B)
FROM TABLE_1
```

I'm inverting the sign of `FIELD_B` in the `ORDER BY`, and the order stays the same :/

Also, I'm using `LAST_VALUE`, but I just want to get the last row according to the `ORDER BY`. Maybe `LAST` would be better, but I don't know how it would fit in here.

Comment: Not up on my oracle syntax but can you put ASC or DESC in your OVERs ORDER BY clauses?  Looking at the oracle site, i think this is doable http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#i97469

Comment: If you're using `LAST_VALUE`, you probably need to specify the windowing clause (as in my answer to a previous question). The default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. i.e the last value seen up to the row you're looking at, not across the whole result set. You can see the difference [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4f09/3). I'm not sure if that's what you mean though.

Comment: The `order by` in the window definition does ***not*** change the order of the rows returned by the `select` statement. It is only relevant for the calculation of the `last_value()` function. If you want the rows to be returned in a specific order, you have to use an `order by` for the whole `select` statement.

Comment: @AlexPoole RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was more of a partition problem, and I ended up using:

```
SELECT
  LAST_VALUE(FIELD_INFO_1) OVER (
    ORDER BY FIELD_A RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ),
  LAST_VALUE(FIELD_INFO_2) OVER (
    ORDER BY FIELD_B RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  )
FROM TABLE_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for but it sounds that you were right and need the LAST function:

```
SELECT
  max(FIELD_INFO_1) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY FIELD_A),
  max(FIELD_INFO_2) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY FIELD_B)
FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: Thanks for the concern :) It was more of a partition problem, and I ended up using RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING.